# How to check the ink level in Epson Stylus DX 4400?

Tags: printing, epson

I have a Epson Stylus DX 4400. I need to see its ink levels in the 4 tanks it has. I tried `MTink` but I can't get it to work.

The printer can't print anymore. I need to know which tank is empty but I cannot see which one!

As I am new to Ubuntu. I have done my best looking for a useful advice on Google before asking here, but couldn't solve the problem. I have found many postings asking for help with Epson printers but I can hardly see any answers.

Comment: OK, MadMike, thank you very much for the information. Really, I didn't know I could see the empty cartridge without a comp... Still, I have found a better solution for me - to buy TurboPrint Control program. It works just flawlessly and has a lot of different possibilities to tune up a printer in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

## Check the empty cartridge without a computer

[image: How to check the ink level]

As per the [Epson DX4400 manual](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX) there is a LED marking the empty cartridge.